# Creating a Canvas at the top of a page

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

The problem I am having is that I want to create a canvas on the top of a webpage but it is always created at the bottom.

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.id = "CursorLayer";
canvas.width = 75;
canvas.height = 25;
//canvas.style.zIndex = 8;
canvas.style.position = "absolute";
canvas.style.border = "1px solid";
canvas.style.display = "inline";
canvas.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(0,0,0,1)';


var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
body.appendChild(canvas);

cursorLayer = document.getElementById("CursorLayer");
var ctx = cursorLayer.getContext("2d");


function daily()
{        
    ctx.fillStyle="#FFFFFF";
    ctx.font="20px Hallo Sans Light";
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.fillText("asdf",1,20);
}
setInterval(daily,1000);
```

If you need to see the webpage just tell me in the comments

Comment: Why are you using JS for CSS?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of `appendChild`, which adds to the end, try `insertBefore`:

```
body.insertBefore(canvas, body.firstChild);
```

Comment: Well, no. He has a variable `body` containing a reference to body. As per his line, `body.appendChild(canvas);`, which we're replacing.

Comment: Ah, so he does - I didn't notice that.  Seems an unusually complicated way to obtain the `body` element...

Comment: Yeah - I didn't want to confuse by discussing stuff unrelated to the question though.

Answer (score 2):

You have positioned it absolute.. Perhaps you missed out:

```
canvas.style.top = 0;
```